# Under what condition can a symmetric matrix becomes PSD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I've just learned the concept of PSD in class, and I've got a little confusion.

If A is a symmetric matrix represented by  $\pmatrix{a&b\\b&c}$, what conditions should be satisfied to becomes a PSD?

What I'm thinking is that all principle minors should be greater or equal to $0$, thus $a\ge0$, $c\ge0$, and $ac-b^2\ge0$. Is these all we need? How about $b$?

Thank you!

Comment: You need eigenvalues to be nonnegative.

Comment: @busyyyy Yes, the conditions $a \geq 0, c \geq 0$ and $ac - b^2 \geq 0$ are necessary and sufficient to guarantee that the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ is positive semidedfinite.